# Flake8 - specify a range of errors to ignores?

Tags: python, lint, flake8

`flake8` supports specifying which error codes should be ignored, for instance:

```
per-file-ignores =
    setup.py:E121,E122,E123
```

However, I wonder whether it is possible to specify a range of errors in the form of `E121-E130` so that all errors that fall within the range `E121-E130` would be ignored (i.e. `E122`, `E123`, `E124` and so forth up to `E130`). I am obviously able to produce a list of these errors code strings programmatically so I don't have to type each of them manually, but it kind of pollutes my `setup.cfg` file.

Is it something that `flake8` supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`per-file-ignores` supports the same syntax as the `ignore` option which is [thoroughly documented](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html).

In short, if you want to ignore all codes that start with `E12` you can do

```
per-file-ignores =
    setup.py:E12
```

Keep in mind that will also ignore `E120`. There's no other "range" operator because we allow users to specify a prefix to match against and that fits the 99% use-case.

Comment: Cool, haven't been able to find this behavior documented (that `E12` will cover everything that starts with `E12`). Thanks